# Compile Can Handle Passing an Empty List Only When Returned by Some Functions?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, warning-messages, compile

There seems to be a bug whereby `Compile` can deal with empty lists only when passed in some cases. Consider the case below.

```
comp1 = Compile[{},
   Join[{{0, 0}}, {}]];

comp1[]

(*output is {{0, 0}}*)
```

No error is thrown and all is well.

Now consider the following.

```
comp2 = Compile[{},
   Join[{{0, 0}}, ConstantArray[{0, 0}, 0]]];

comp2[]

(*output is {{0, 0}}*)
```

In this case, the following error is thrown.

[image: error message]

The outputs are rightfully the same, but it doesn't seem like the second case should throw an error and be uncompilable. Not only are `ConstantArray[{0, 0}, 0]` and `{}` equal; they are identical, as measured by `SameQ`.

```
ConstantArray[{0, 0}, 0] === {}

(*output is True*)
```

*What is going on here?*

I have code that requires the use of `ConstantArray` as above, but I want it to compile and not to throw an error. *Are there any suggestions on how to deal with this?*

- A similar issue is mentioned in ["instruction 9223372036854775807" Bug and Bug with Using DeleteCases[] inside Compile[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/255258/12697). However, there are two differences. In the case presented in the present question, the error is produced using `ConstantArray`, which is even more simple than `DeleteCases` or `Table`. More importantly, the error thrown is different.

---

### Notes

- My OS is macOS Big Sur Version 11.2.3
- My Mathematica version is 12.1.1.0

Comment: ``MemberQ[Compile`CompilerFunctions[], ConstantArray]`` gives `False` , that is, `ConstantArray` is not compilable. Related: [List of compilable functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/125)

Comment: @kglr But it seems like `ConstantArray` is, in fact, compilable. `comp = Compile[{},
   Join[{}, ConstantArray[1, 1]]]; comp[]` gives the expected output with no error, for example. This may be another issue.

Comment: @kglr If you look further down on your link, it does include ConstantArray[] as compilable.

Comment: If you read further down @kglr's link, to "Edit 2", you will see there are two meanings to "compilable."  `ConstantArray` is not compilable in the first & most important sense, as is shown in WReach's answer (`ConstantArray` is evaluated via `MainEvaluate`, not in the compiled run-time environment WVM).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Do you know why such a [very] basic function is not compilable in the first sense?

Comment: No, I don't. You can use `Table` instead. `ConstantArray` is a new function (2007); prior to that, one used `Table`. They're nearly interchangeable except for one usage: `ConstantArray[c, {10, 10}, SparseArray]`. While that usage would not be compilable, it is common that compiler versions of functions have restricted usages (restricted to numeric/boolean arrays, most obviously).

Comment: @MichaelE2 When I run `comp2 = Compile[{}, Join[{{0, 0}}, Table[{0, 0}, 0]]]; comp2[]` I get an error. However, `comp2 = Compile[{}, Join[{{0, 0}}, Array[{0, 0} &, 0]]]; comp2[]` does work. It seems using `Table` does not work but `Array` does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Root Cause**

The root cause of the error is that we are attempting to join tensors of incompatible shapes.  Namely, a 1x2 array...

```
Dimensions[{{0,0}}]
(* {1, 2} *)
```

... with a zero-length one-dimensional array:

```
Dimensions[ConstantArray[{0, 0}, 0]]
(* {0} *)

Dimensions[{}]
(* {0} *)
```

While this is permitted by the main evaluator, the compiler applies stricter type-checking rules.  So when the compiled code is executed and this mismatch is detected then evaluation drops back to the main evaluator.  This produces the correct result but issues a warning to indicate that the main evaluator was used unexpectedly.

**Manifestly Empty Lists Optimized Out**

But... if this is the case then why does `comp1` not issue the warning message?  The reason is that the compiler has optimized the `Join` expression when one of the arguments is explicitly an empty list:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[comp1]
```

[image: compiled comp1 code]

Notice how instruction 1 calls `Join` with a single argument.  The second argument, the explicitly empty list, has been optimized out.  (Interestingly, the `Join` is not optimized out when it is reduced to a single argument.)

***ConstantArray* Expressions Not Optimized Out**

Now contrast this with the code of `comp2`:

```
CompilePrint[comp2]
```

[image: compiled comp2 code]

This time instruction 2 shows a two-argument call to `Join`.  The compiler has not been able to recognize that the second argument will result in an empty list.  That argument will be passed to the main evaluator to evaluate the `ConstantArray` expression.

Note that instruction 1 is expecting the result of the `ConstantArray` expression to be a two-dimensional tensor of integers (*T(I2)*).  So it is surprised when the result turns out to be an empty one-dimensional list. The compiled code bails out and the `Join` expression is evaluated by the main evaluator (accompanied by a warning message due to the unplanned use of `MainEvaluate` for `Join`).

**Different Reproduction Case**

We can reproduce this behaviour by expressing the empty list by a different, fully-compilable expression:

```
comp3 = Compile[{}, Join[{{0, 0}}, {{0, 0}}[[;; 0]]]];

CompilePrint[comp3]
```

[image: compiled comp3 code]

Here again the compiler has not recognized that `{{0, 0}}[[;; 0]]` will be an empty list that could be optimized out of instruction 2.  The `Part` expression is compiled, so unlike the previous example there is no explicit call to `MainEvaluate`.  But this will also incur the type mismatch and fall back on the main evaluator implicitly for the `Join` (albeit with a slightly different warning message):

```
comp3[]
```

[image: comp3 evaluation output]

**Workaround #1 - Explicit Guard**

As far as I know, there is no way to represent a 2 x 0 matrix in *Mathematica*.  Such an array always collapses into an empty one-dimensional list (e.g. `Dimensions@Array[0, {0, 2}] === Dimensions@SparseArray[{}, {0, 2}] === Dimensions@Array[0, {0, 2, 3, 4}] === {0}`).

So, assuming that we do not know *a priori* whether or not this situation is going to occur then we could introduce an explicit guard for the case.  For example:

```
comp4 =
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}}
  , With[{a = {0, 0}}
    , If [n == 0, {a}, Join[{a}, ConstantArray[a, n]]]
    ]
  ];

comp4[1]
(* {{0, 0}, {0, 0}} *)

comp4[0]
(* {{0, 0}} *)
```

**Workaround #2 - Compiler Type Trickery**

[Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) notes in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255507/compile-can-handle-passing-an-empty-list-only-when-returned-by-some-functions/255514#comment637040_255514) that there does exist at least one compilation path in which the type system will preserve the two-dimensional structure of an empty array.  It involves a combination of `Most` and `Table`:

```
comp5 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Most@Table[{0, 0}, {n+1}]];

comp5[1]
(* {{0, 0}, {0, 0}} *)

comp5[0]
(* {{0, 0}} *)
```

This trick of preserving the 2x0 tensor structure *only* works in compiled code.  The main evaluator still collapses `Most@Table[{0, 0}, 1]` into an empty one-dimensional list.

The compiled code for this variation is a bit more elaborate than the other versions as it involves explicit instructions to construct the temporary `Table` and drop the last element:

[image: compiled comp5 code]

*This analysis is current as of Mathematica version 12.2.0.*

Comment: FWIW, `Compile[{}, Join[{{0, 0}}, Most@Table[{0, 0}, 1]]]`  runs without error or bailing out of the WVM. And `Compile[{}, Dimensions@Most@Table[{0, 0}, 1]]` returns `{0,2}`, which does not occur in the main evaluator of course..

Comment: @MichaelE2 Nice find!  I have updated my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: Would you consider the base problem a bug or just a quirk?

Comment: Hmmm, tough call.  I'm going to go with "quirk".  Compiling and imposing strong types on a fluid language like WL is intrinsically difficult (maybe impossible).  For example, in WL one can redefine `;` but the compiler will make strong assumptions about (apparently) simple expression sequencing.  Closer to the case at hand, WL purposefully blurs the distinction between row and column vectors, but a compiler will want to be more strict.  So I feel that we will be faced with such compilation quirks for a long time to come.  None of this navel-gazing prevents raising a support ticket :)

Comment: Here's my contribution for Confuse-A-Compiler Day: `$/:HoldPattern[a_;$;b_]:=(b;a);Compile[{},Print[1];$;Print[2]][]`  :D